# Installing Openbravo with database backup file

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, openbravo

How to install openbravo with database backup?

I have a postgresql dump file and I want to install openbravo with this sql file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Steps To dump database locally

1)Open pgadmin GUI, create new database say 'db_name'

2)Go to command prompt, issue following***(sql_File_Path may vary)***

C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin>psql -U postgres -f sql_File_Path db_name

3)Edit the Openbravo.properties file ***bbdd.sid=db_name***

4)ant smartbuild -Dlocal=no

5)Restart the tomcat.

***Note:***
You should have a compiled source code of Openbravo , Otherwise you will get an error during Smartbuild.

Comment: Thanx for the answer,I am not  getting the second step and rest everything is clear and do things change when working in linux?

Comment: In Linux(Ubuntu)--> Open Terminal and go to the location where postgresql binaries  installed ( cd /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/bin) then execute the same command , it should work fine